# How do I add youtube support to Safari 11.0?

Tags: safari, video, youtube

Safari 11.0 on High Sierra does not play any youtube.com videos. It displays instead:

```
Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available.
Click here to visit our frequently asked questions about HTML5 video.
```

[image: safari does not support youtube screenshot]

Youtube videos work just fine on Chrome, but just avoiding advertising bombardment has been enough to become a fan of Safari (even though it's particularly slow at reading my brief start-up HTML file).

How do I add youtube support to Safari 11.0?

Comment: I don't have any problem playing youtube videos on my MBP.  Do you have any content blockers or HTML5 blockers on your system?

Comment: @fsb Thanks for the hint. I did in fact have Ad Block, but it wasn't the one. I also had some legacy "Click To Flash" (third-party?) Safari extension. Youtube videos play when I disable that extension.

Comment: Safari doesn't even has supoort for 4K videos but mine works fine with support upto 2K videos, don't know why yours not able to play YouTube videos are you sure you haven't changed anything under developer settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Safari \ Preferences. Click on Extensions. If you see the extension "ClickToFlash", disable it.
[image: ClickToFlash Safari extension]